# Trouble installing Angular 2 quickstart project dependencies

Tags: angular, npm

I'm having problems getting started with the [Angular 2 Quickstart Project](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and in particular performing an `npm install`.

I'm getting a certificate error back:

> typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "es6-shim". 
>   You should check the  entry paths in "es6-shim.d.ts" are up to date typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts"
>   typings ERR! caused by unable to get local issuer certificate

I am behind a proxy in a corp environment and have tried to get around this with `strict-ssl = false` in my npm config, but this has made no difference.

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `set HTTP_PROXY=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port`

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt, set proxy.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port
npm config set proxy=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port
npm config set https-proxy=http://your_username:your_password@domain_name:port
```

This should solve the issue

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure what values to enter here. Are you talking about my login details I use for logging into my company network on the machine I'm using?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about your login details.